# How to resolve an error in Importing CSV file from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I want to import a CSV file to PostgreSQL.

Shown below is the syntax used to import a CSV file to a created table i.e. **salary_supervisor** in PostgreSQL,

```
COPY salary_supervisor 
FROM 'X:\XX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\supervisor_salaries.csv' /* File path */
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

However, it indicates an error as shown below,

```
ERROR:  could not open file "X:\XX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\supervisor_salaries.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

Since an error was shown above, the below syntax was used to import the CSV file to PostgreSQL,

```
\copy (Select * From salary_supervisor) 
FROM 'X:\XX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\supervisor_salaries.csv'  /* File path */
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

However, it also indicated a syntax error shown below,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy (Select * From salary_supervisor) 
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` (meta) command and can only be used within `psql`

Comment: `COPY` runs as the database server user, so the file you are trying to import needs to be accessible by that user.